# Data stores in JavaScript or Jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

I am developing a site which retrieve few lists (like country, product, industry) from share point using a soap call, and load the drop-downs. Later there are few filtration and reload of country dropdown based upon selected region.

Instead of making a soap call each time I was thinking if I can use java-script to once retrieve all the lists and store it on client side and reference it to reload the drops downs, something like `List<>, Dictionary<> or hash tables in c#`, something which can support key/value concept.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. NO. **NO.** jQuery is Javascript, it's just a library.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance : It would be helpfull if you express your feelings before marking a downvote, So I can understand whats wrong.

Comment: Read the whole of the comment...

Comment: jQuery is Javascript doesn't make sense of down voting, both jquery have few plug-ins to help anyway never mind.

Comment: I'm saying there's no such thing as jQuery vs Javascript, as jQuery IS in Javascript.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: jQuery is *written in* JavaScript. It's deceiving to say that it *is* JavaScript. Seems to me that OP is asking about storage approaches. This could involve only language level structures (objects), could involve host provided capabilities (like localStorage), or could involve library-provided capabilities (like `jQuery.data`).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) to keep your object on the browser side. Here's a link to an example of getting data from the server and using JSON on the browser side http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/211489/Using-JSON-with-ASP-NET-3-5